# ‘Induction on’ vs ‘Induction with respect to’ in math

Tags: terminology

I heard one mathematician who said “induction **on** ” and another who said “induction **with respect to** ”.  Do these two expressions mean exactly the same thing mathematically?

- If so, then are they both correct ways to say this and which is more common?
- If not, then what shade of difference is there between the two phrases?

Comment: As far as I know, both are the same. Both sound correct to me. I'd say the shorter myself.

Comment: You can have induction on other, possibly finite sets, e.g. $X=\{0,~1\},$ with $S:X\to X,$ $S(0)=1,$ $S(1)=0,$ and $X=\{ 0, ~S(0)\}.$

Answer (score 7):

Yes, these expressions mean exactly the same thing.  Both are correct; in my experience, ``induction on n'' is more common.  Usually, the shorter the phrase, the more likely it is to be widely adopted.

Comment: For that matter, when the parameter to-be-inducted-upon is clear, one would simply say "by induction", without reference to the parameter, which is surely just a "dummy", in any case. :)